# how to set MX Panel title back color

Tags: css, actionscript-3, air, panel

I want to set the background color of MX Panel. I can change the text color of the title but can not change the background color.

I'm using below code:

```
.Panel {
        textAlign: center;
        borderColor: #33cccc;
        borderThicknessLeft: 6;
        borderThicknessTop: 0;
        borderThicknessBottom: 10;
        borderThicknessRight: 6;
        roundedBottomCorners: true;
        cornerRadius: 8;
        headerHeight: 22;
        backgroundAlpha: 0.97;
        highlightAlphas: 0.34, 0.06;
        dropShadowEnabled: true;
        shadowDistance: 8;
        shadowDirection: left;
        dropShadowColor: #5b3d24;
        titleStyleName: "mypanelTitle"; 

    }

    .mypanelTitle {
        background-color: #5b3d24;
        color: #5b3d24;
        background: #5b3d24;
        fontFamily: Arial;
        fontSize: 12;
        fontWeight: bold;
    }
```

Please help me to set the title color.

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try backgroundColor? It works fine for me for mx:Panel (flex 4.6).

***UPDATE:***

Sorry, my previous answer was incorrect. If you use Halo theme you can try headerColors style property (I cannot test it now).

Second way - create your own custom skin for title. It will be looks like next:

*Main.mxml*

```
<mx:Panel x="428" y="21" width="250" height="200" layout="absolute" title="Title Text" titleBackgroundSkin="CustomTitleBackgroundSkin">
```

*CustomTitleBackgroundSkin.as*

```
package
{
import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class CustomTitleBackgroundSkin extends UIComponent
{
    public function CustomTitleBackgroundSkin()
    {
        super();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
}
```

P.S. In css property titleBackgroundSkin will be look next:

```
    .panel {
        titleBackgroundSkin: ClassReference("CustomTitleBackgroundSkin");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but not working. Can you please send me sample code? I'm doing it in AIR.

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully, so I misunderstood you. So I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey!!! You are great! It worked for me. Thank you so much. Actually I'm a .Net developer and Windows Azure architect. But now working on small Adobe Air app. I salute you.